# Javascript selective inheritance while object creation

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

Lets say I have an object relations like that;

```
var firstObject = {     prop1:"prop1",  prop2:"prop2" };

var secondObject = Object.create(firstObject);

secondObject.prop3 = "prop3";

secondObject.prop4 = "prop4";

var thirdObject =  Object.create(secondObject);
```

At the above code when I have created thirdObject it will also inherit firstObject properties which is expected. What I wonder is , are there any elegant (I mean without 
iterating over secondObject properties with hasOwnProperty property) ways to
inherit just secondObject properties while creating thirdObject?

Comment: In ES2015 you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)`(thirdObject, secondObject)` which will just copy own properties instead of inheriting them prototypically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> are there any elegant (I mean without iterating over secondObject properties with hasOwnProperty property) ways to inherit just secondObject properties while creating thirdObject?

No, and in fact, there's no (reasonable*) inelegant way to do it either; making `thirdObject` *inherit* from `secondObject` means it will inherit all of `secondObject`'s properties and the ones from its prototype(s).

If you want `thirdObject` not to have `firstObject`'s properties, `thirdObject` shouldn't inherit (indirectly) from `firstObject`.

Three options for you (and an "unreasonable" fourth later):

#### Copy the properties

You could use `Object.assign` to *copy* `secondObject`'s own properties to `thirdObject`:

```
var thirdObject = Object.assign({}, secondObject);
```

...but it wouldn't be inheritance, just a snapshot. But that might be for the best. (`Object.assign` was added in ES2015 [aka "ES6"], but can be polyfilled for older JavaScript engines.)

#### Mimic inheritance with getters/setters

Alternately, and this does require iterating `secondObject`'s own properties, you could give `thirdObject` matching properties with getters and setters:

```js
var firstObject = { prop1:"prop1", prop2:"prop2" };

var secondObject = Object.create(firstObject);

secondObject.prop3 = "prop3";

secondObject.prop4 = "prop4";

var thirdObject = {};
Object.keys(secondObject).forEach(function(key) {
  Object.defineProperty(thirdObject, key, {
    get: function() {
      return secondObject[key];
    },
    set: function(value) {
      delete this[key];  // Release the getter/setter for this
      this[key] = value; // ...and make it an own property
    },
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true
  });
});

console.log("prop1" in firstObject);  // true
console.log("prop1" in secondObject); // true
console.log("prop1" in thirdObject);  // false
console.log("--");
console.log("prop3" in firstObject);  // false
console.log("prop3" in secondObject); // true
console.log("prop3" in thirdObject);  // true
console.log("--");
console.log(firstObject.prop1);  // prop1
console.log(secondObject.prop1); // prop1
console.log(thirdObject.prop1);  // undefined
console.log("--");
console.log(firstObject.prop3);  // undefined
console.log(secondObject.prop3); // prop3
console.log(thirdObject.prop3);  // prop3
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

There, we mimic inheritance by having `thirdObject` get the value from `secondObject` until/unless something assigns a value to it, in which case we make it a standard data property.

#### Use inheritance with an intermediary with getters

Or you could make `thirdObject` inherit from an intermediary that defers to `secondObject`'s own properties instead (a bit simpler, and then the "own" flags are right):

```js
var firstObject = { prop1:"prop1", prop2:"prop2" };

var secondObject = Object.create(firstObject);

secondObject.prop3 = "prop3";

secondObject.prop4 = "prop4";

var thirdProto = {};
Object.keys(secondObject).forEach(function(key) {
  Object.defineProperty(thirdProto, key, {
    get: function() {
      return secondObject[key];
    },
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true
  });
});
var thirdObject = Object.create(thirdProto);

console.log("prop1" in firstObject);  // true
console.log("prop1" in secondObject); // true
console.log("prop1" in thirdObject);  // false
console.log("--");
console.log("prop3" in firstObject);  // false
console.log("prop3" in secondObject); // true
console.log("prop3" in thirdObject);  // true
console.log("--");
console.log(firstObject.prop1);  // prop1
console.log(secondObject.prop1); // prop1
console.log(thirdObject.prop1);  // undefined
console.log("--");
console.log(firstObject.prop3);  // undefined
console.log(secondObject.prop3); // prop3
console.log(thirdObject.prop3);  // prop3
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

* The *unreasonable* way would be to use a `Proxy` (ES2015+, not polyfillable):

```js
var firstObject = { prop1:"prop1", prop2:"prop2" };

var secondObject = Object.create(firstObject);

secondObject.prop3 = "prop3";

secondObject.prop4 = "prop4";

var thirdObject = Object.create(new Proxy(secondObject, {
    has: function(target, prop) {
        return target.hasOwnProperty(prop) || secondObject.hasOwnProperty(prop);
    },
    get: function(target, prop) {
        return target.hasOwnProperty(prop) || secondObject.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? target[prop] : undefined;
    },
    set: function(target, prop, value) {
        target[prop] = value;
        return true;
    }
}));

console.log("prop1" in firstObject);  // true
console.log("prop1" in secondObject); // true
console.log("prop1" in thirdObject);  // false
console.log("--");
console.log("prop3" in firstObject);  // false
console.log("prop3" in secondObject); // true
console.log("prop3" in thirdObject);  // true
console.log("--");
console.log(firstObject.prop1);  // prop1
console.log(secondObject.prop1); // prop1
console.log(thirdObject.prop1);  // undefined
console.log("--");
console.log(firstObject.prop3);  // undefined
console.log(secondObject.prop3); // prop3
console.log(thirdObject.prop3);  // prop3
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
Note: Requires a browser with <code>Proxy</code> support.
```

...**but** I can't imagine you want a proxy object in your inheritance chain, not least because of the effect it would have on performance. :-) So I **wouldn't** do that. (And I'm sure the example above is incomplete.)